# Ruby: How to group a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby array

```
> list = Request.find_all_by_artist("Metallica").map(&:song)
=> ["Nothing else Matters", "Enter sandman", "Enter Sandman", "Master of Puppets", "Master of Puppets", "Master of Puppets"]
```

and I want a list with the counts like this:

```
{"Nothing Else Matters" => 1,
 "Enter Sandman" => 2,
 "Master of Puppets" => 3}
```

So ideally I want a hash that will give me the count and notice how I have `Enter Sandman` and `enter sandman` so I need it case insensitive. I am pretty sure I can loop through it but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
list.group_by(&:capitalize).map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}
#=> [["Master of puppets", 3], ["Enter sandman", 2], ["Nothing else matters", 1]]
```

The group by creates a hash from the `capitalize`d version of an album name to an array containing all the strings in `list` that match it (e.g. `"Enter sandman" => ["Enter Sandman", "Enter sandman"]`). The `map` then replaces each array with its length, so you get e.g. `["Enter sandman", 2]` for `"Enter sandman"`.

If you need the result to be a hash, you can call `to_h` on the result or wrap a `Hash[ ]` around it.

Answer (score 12):

As of Ruby 2.7, you can use `Enumerable#tally`.

```
list.tally
# => {"Nothing else Matters"=>1, "Enter sandman"=>1, "Enter Sandman"=>1, "Master of Puppets"=>3}
```

Comment: I think this answer should be chosen as the best answer!

Answer (score 11):

```
list.inject(Hash.new(0)){|h,k| k.downcase!; h[k.capitalize] += 1;h}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another take:

```
h = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = 0}
list.each {|song| h[song.downcase] += 1}
p h  # => {"nothing else matters"=>1, "enter sandman"=>2, "master of puppets"=>3}
```

As I commented, you might prefer [`titlecase`](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/294)

Comment: In this case you don't need to use the block form of Hash.new. So you can just do `h = Hash.new(0)`.

Answer (score 5):

Grouping and sorting of a data set of unknown size in Ruby should be a choice of last resort. This is a chore best left to DB. Typically problems like yours is solved using a combination of `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses.  Fortunately, rails provides a `count` method for such use cases.

```
song_counts= Request.count(
              :select => "LOWER(song) AS song"
              :group => :song, :order=> :song,
              :conditions => {:artist => "Metallica"})

song_counts.each do |song, count|
  p "#{song.titleize} : #{count}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but clean answer I have,

```
l = list.group_by(&:titleize)
l.merge(l) { |k,v| l[k] = v.count }
```

Note: If we do want unique keys i.e. without `titleize`, then replace it with `itself`

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["Nothing else Matters", "Enter sandman", "Enter Sandman", "Master of Puppets", "Master of Puppets", "Master of Puppets"]

list.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|k,v| v[k.downcase] += 1}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.